# How to secure Web services in ASMX file?

Tags: c#, web-services, security, asmx

I have some critical db connection done through web service .asmx file which is accessible and can be open through direct browse through browser How to prevent some methods and allow some methods to access general unauthenticated users?

This problem is so severe to my application.

Answer (score 7):

One common method is to use an access token in all web service calls.  The scenario would be something like this:

1. User calls a "login" web service method, passing some credentials.  (This *should* be over a secure connection, you might want to require SSL for this, if you don't already for all of them.)
2. The "login" web service method authenticates the user, generates an access token (a Guid works nicely), stores that access token (perhaps with a window of time for which the token is usable), and returns that token to the user in the response.
3. All subsequent web service methods (everything that needs to be secured) requires that an access token be provided as a method argument.  The user passes that access token in all of their calls.
4. Each time a web service method is called, the system validates the access token against the known generated tokens (accounting for a window of time, if you want tokens to expire, which I recommend) and, if it's not a currently valid token, denies the request.

If you've ever used the Facebook API, that's one common example of needing to [request a time-sensitive access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) in order to make subsequent API calls.